# Angular 2 tem a possibilidade de fazer uma string ser interpretada como html?

Tags: javascript, angular

Eu tenho uma variável chamada "link_youtube", que contem um dado semelhante a este:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eNs5g-c1Qno?list=RDeNs5g-c1Qno" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

porém o browser não identifica isso como um html, ele identifica como uma string, preciso que o meu sistema identifique isso como uma HTML, alguém poderia me ajudar?

segue abaixo o código html:

```
insira o código aqui
<div class="text-center">
    <h1>{{sPCrtl.campanha.titulo}}</h1>
    {{sPCrtl.campanha.biografia_campanha.link_youtube}}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
<div [innerHtml]="iframeYoutube"></div>
```

---

### UPDATE

Realmente precisa de mais coisa para inserir um iframe, ja havia testado com html normal, mas iframe o angular bloqueia logo de cara. Desculpa pela resposta rasa.

Você precisa injetar o `DomSanitizer` do angular para poder injetar seu iframe:

```
iframeYoutube: SafeHtml;
```

Crie uma variável do tipo `SafeHtml` do pacote `@angular/platform-browser`

Injete o `DomSanitizer`, também do pacote `@angular/platform-browser`, no construtor do seu component:

```
constructor(
  ...
  private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ...
) {}
```

E finalmente no momento que você for injetar o iframe na div faça:

```
iframeYoutube = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtube.com/embed/2dAY9dh-HWo"; frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`);
```

Comment: Olá Giovane, tentei utilizar o comando da seguinte forma <div [innerHtml]= "<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2dAY9dh-HWo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>" - não funcionou :/

Comment: tentei utilizar, this.iframe = "<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2dAY9dh-HWo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>"   HTML:  <div [innerHtml] = "{{ctrl.iframe}}" = também não funcionou.

Comment: Sera que devo importar alguma dependência ?

Comment: @MatheusFreitas atualizei a resposta, realmente eu não tinha testado com iframe e ja passei a resposta pois ja havia injetado html desta maneira antes. Você vai ter um pouquinho a mais de trabalho para lidar com iframe.